# writing first package; function not found

Tags: r, package

I'm working on my first package ([GitHub](https://github.com/ericpgreen/qualtrics)). Pretty basic. [Two functions](https://github.com/ericpgreen/qualtricsR/blob/master/R/qualtricsR.R).

```
R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source qualtricsR
library(qualtricsR)
```

Works fine as far as I can tell. Running `check` in RStudio results in a final message of `R CMD check succeeded`.

However, when I try to run my functions (e.g., `template <- importTemplate("inst/doc/template.xlsx")`), I get an error that R cannot find my function. `?importTemplate` shows my help page.

Comment: Have you added your functions to the NAMESPACE file? In the link that you give that file seems to be empty, it should contain `export(importTemplate, writeQtxt)`.

Comment: you need to export, see the roxygen2 docs

Comment: great. adding `export(importTemplate)` and `export(writeQtxt)` to `NAMESPACE` did the trick. running `devtools::document()` automated this process once I added `#' @export` before the function in my `.R` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jablacalle and @mdsumner put me on the right track.

Adding `export(importTemplate)` and `export(writeQtxt)` to `NAMESPACE` did the trick. running `devtools::document()` automated this process once I added `#' @export` before the function in my `.R` file.